# What program can I use to compress (zip,rar...) and password protect files on my Android Froyo

Tags: 2.2-froyo, password

I was just sending a backup via mail to my Google account.

This backup contained readable information (csv format) from sensitive data.

Does anyone knows of a program to compress files (in .zip format, or .rar if necessary) on my Android phone (running Froyo), with a password protection used while compressing.

That way I can compress/protect my data before sending it via email.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dual File Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/dual-file-manager/it.medieval.dualfm)

Comment: It appears that the program is now called [Dual File Manager XT](http://www.appbrain.com/app/dual-file-manager-xt/it.medieval.dualfm_xt)